# package-lock.jsonのintegrity

Tags: npm

package-lock.jsonファイルに書かれている`integrity`とは何ですか。
[ドキュメント](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json#integrity)を見てもよくわかりませんでした。
どのタイミングで何のために生成される値なのでしょうか。